# How to get specific view touched/clicked from RecyclerView?

Tags: android, list, touch, adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that holds a list of items. Each item is a RelativeLayout that holds four textviews. What I would like to do is be able to differentiate between which textview of the list item is clicked, and then perform an action based on that.

Right now I am using

```
final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MyShiftsPageFragment.this.getActivity(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    shiftList.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            ViewGroup child = (ViewGroup) recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

            if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                Log.i(TAG, child.toString());
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "TouchEvent");
        }
    });
```

But all it seems to find is the RelativeLayout, not an individual component on top of that layout. Any ideas? Or is there a different way I should go about doing this?

Comment: Why aren't you registering an `OnClickListener` or `OnTouchListener` on the `TextViews` themselves?

Comment: Where would I do that? In my ViewHolder class in my adapter?

Comment: "In my ViewHolder class in my adapter?" -- sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code from a sample I put together, the events seem to trigger properly.

```
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener {

        private CheckBox mCheckBox;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public CheckBox getCheckBox() {
            return mCheckBox;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("CustomAdapter.ViewHolder", "item onClick()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d("CustomAdapter.ViewHolder", "checkbox onCheckChanged()");
        }

    }
```

Of course, you don't have to have the ViewHolder implement the listener interfaces, you can create the listener however you want.

Comment: Well, I would like to keep item selection capability since I would like the selection areas to be either the TextView OR the rest of the item.

Comment: Okay, I did some research and rather than using OnItemTouchListener, you can implement onClickListener in the ViewHolder and register the listener on the item's view when the ViewHolder is created.  You'd probably still have to jack around with descendantFocusability on the view to get the TextView click to coexist with the item click.  

You can try setting android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on the item's view and android:textIsSelectable="false" on the TextViews.

I haven't worked with RecyclerView yet so I'm going to hack some code together tonight and update my answer.

Comment: @bohica In your sample, how to get the position of the clicked item?

Comment: ViewHolder has a getPosition() method, so assuming your listener was an inner class of the ViewHolder (I didn't do it that way), you could call getPosition() in your listener.

I should have done a more complete example, but I was in a bit of a rush just to check that the events were sorting out correctly.

Comment: @Mike Reinhart please accept my answer as correct if that's working for you - thx